# Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I get this error in my tests while I try to test a fail of a promise:

> Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

```
it('should fail on the getInfo request', function (done) {                  
    SideCtrl.accInfo.getInfo.and.returnValue(Promise.reject({}));
    SideCtrl.accInfo.getInfo().then(() => {}).catch(() => {                
        expect(SideCtrl.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            first_name: '',
            last_name: ''
        });
        done();
    });
});
```

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a spy anywhere on `SideCtrl.accInfo.getInfo()`? If not this is probably your problem. You need to spy on the function and return the promise manually. Something like this should work.

```
spyOn(SideCtrl.accInfo, 'getInfo').and.callFake(() => {
    const deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.reject({});
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

You can also do it this way

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(_$q_) => {
    const getInfoDeferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn(SideCtrl.accInfo, 'getInfo').and.returnValue(getInfoDeferred.promise);
}


it('should fail on the getInfo request', function (done) {
    SideCtrl.accInfo.getInfo();                  
    getInfoDeferred.reject({});
    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(SideCtrl.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        first_name: '',
        last_name: ''
    });
    done();
});
```

});

You need to kick off the digest cycle to get the promise to return. You can do that by calling `$rootScope.$apply()` or `$rootScope.$digest()`.